Rescaling Kp-fonts in plain tex
I am using Kp-fonts in a plain tex (not LaTeX) document.  I invoke them with the line:
\input kp-fonts

They work fine at the default size.
But in some cases I would like to rescale these.  So I type, say:
\font\bigger=KpRoman-Regular at 36pt

and then I try to switch to this font by typing \bigger.  This causes MikTeX to fail with the messages:

Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed for the following reason:
No creation rule for font KpRoman-Regular.

and

\title=KpRoman-Regular at 36.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.

Can I download the relevant .tfm file from somewhere?  If so, where do I install it?  If not, what alternatives are there?  Or is it possible that "KpRoman-Regular" was just the wrong guess for the font name?

sorry but if they work at the default size you must know the correct font name.

@UlrikeFischer:  Actually, I don't, because I invoke them by inputting a standard package called kp-fonts, and I'm not sure exactly where that's stored.  But of course you're right that I ought to be able to dig around, find it, and see what the font names are.  I'll do that now.

You ought also to include in your question the code you use when you're doing that so we can reproduce the 'working fine' as a baseline.

@cfr ... doing that now.

presumably /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/csplain/fonts/kp-fonts.tex which contains extensive comments, also it's probably largely superseded by optex these days

\input kpfonts errors for me in a current miktex.

http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/bulletin/kpfonts-plain.pdf has extensive documentation including how to load fonts at different sizes

You've missed the hyphen.

@cfr :  Thanks; editing.


loads kp fonts at two sizes

\input kp-fonts
\ffletfont\bigrm = {\rm}{at20pt}
\rm  aaaa

\bigrm aaa

\bye

see http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/bulletin/kpfonts-plain.pdf

This is great.  I didn't know about "ffletfont".  Thanks so much.

Perhaps one difference between you and me is that you knew where to look for the file!

@WillO Doesn't MikTeX have kpsewhich?

Full relative path ....

You did say 'every file input'. Maybe I shouldn't have read that as in the scope of a universal.

You can also just use \show to get the name if you load the package which provides the font you want. For example,
\input kp-fonts.tex regular
% \show\rm
\font\bigger=jkpmn8t at 36pt \bigger bigger



Thank you.  You and David Carlisle both leapt in to help and I'm most grateful.

I had not known about \show.  It is clearly going to be useful in a lot of other contexts going forward.  Thank you again.

@WillO There's a little family of them ;). \showthe is also very useful.
